# How can I get id from url with Request $request? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, routes, request, laravel-5.3

My link href on the view is like this :

```
<a href="{{ route('message.inbox.detail.id', ['id' => $message->id]) }}" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="fa fa-eye"></span> {{ trans('button.view') }}
</a>
```

My routes is like this :

```
Route::get('message/inbox/detail/id/{id}', ['as'=>'message.inbox.detail.id','uses'=>'MessageController@detail']);
```

When clicked, the url display like this :

```
http://myshop.dev/message/inbox/detail/id/58cadfba607a1d2ac4000254
```

I want get id with `Request $request`

On the controller, I try like this :

```
public function detail(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->input('id'));
}
```

The result : null

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 14):

You can get it like this

```
$request->route('id')
```

Inside request class you can access it this way

```
$this->route('id')
```

I usually use it when I'm validating field to make sure it's unique, and I need to exclude model by ID when I'm doing update

Comment: This is the correct answer, worth noting it may not be `id`. The parameter you pass should be the same name as the parameter in the route definition.

Comment: @rosscooper Exactly. If you defined the route like this: `Route::apiresource('car', 'Api\CarController')`, you have to use `$request->route('car')` or `$request->route()->parameters['car']`. You can get the request object with `request()`,  `$request` which is coming from the controller method's parameter, or `$this` inside a request object.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're passing the id parameter through url, you should send it using a form like this

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>' route('message.inbox.detail.id', 'method'=> 'POST']) !!}
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $message->id }}" />
{!! Form::submit({{ trans('button.view') }}, ['class'=>'btn btn-default']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and now you can access via request in your controller

```
public function detail(Request $request)
{


 dd($request->input('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who are looking for answers using newer versions of laravel, you can get the route id using the following:

Example route with model binding

```
Route::put('/post/{post}, [PostController::class, 'update]);
```

`$this->route('id')` will not work in this case due to model binding.

instead you can do this:

```
// using in controller
request()->route('post.id);
```

or

```
// using in form request
$this->route('post.id');
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the id via this:

```
public function detail($id)
{
   dd($id);
}
```

Comment: Does it can not use parameters `Request $request`?

Comment: for `get`, this is how you will have to pass it into your controller, `Request $request` can be used in other http method.